# Is this the best method to split Python code into dependent modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a program I'm writing. It's becoming too large to manage well: it has a lot of code related to GUI functionality (PyQt5), and it's nearly 2000 lines. I understand that in Python, it is acceptable to have large scripts that are coded completely in one file, but writing this program has become unmanageable. I can't easily organize the code in one file. I previously tried to split it into multiple files (using methods I'd found here on StackOverflow), but to no avail. I finally just realized what I might have to do for my situation. (I know that realistically, you'd never split the following into two files, but I'm using it as an example.) Here is a very simple example of a script split in two (file 1):

```
# TestProg.py

class Name:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def testfunc():
    nm.name += nm.name[int(len(nm.name)/2):]  # Add to name, second half of name
    return nm.name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import TestModule
    print(TestModule.returnName(TestModule.nm))
    input()
```

File 2:

```
# TestModule.py

import TestProg

Name = TestProg.Name
testfunc = TestProg.testfunc


nm = Name('Henry')

def returnName(name):
    return name.name[::-1] + testfunc()
```

If you try running this, it won't work. I finally figured out it's because of the fact that `testfunc` is defined in `TestProg` and uses a global variable (which isn't defined in `TestProg`). To solve this problem, you must modify the globals dict of `testfunc`, with `testfunc.__globals__['nm'] = nm`, and place that in `TestModule` right after you define `nm`.

I understand this is not a pretty thing to do, but it seems to be the best way I can think of to do it. Now, I know, "Just use a local variable/parameter for `testfunc`, instead of global." The thing is, it *is* a global variable (which needs to be defined in a file separate from the function in the split). I don't want to have to pass the variable to the function every time, that's very tedious, repetitive, and a waste of time. My question is: **is** there a better way to do it? I would assume no. A secondary question is: is this method acceptable? Is it considered a hack/highly unpythonic, and therefore unwise to use?

Please remember, I really need the file to be split, but I can't really split it any nicer than that which requires this method to work (as far as I know).

Comment: have you considered `from TestProg import Name, testfunc` ?

Comment: I also was in a situation where I needed to split a Python script as it was getting extremely huge. This is how I did it: https://github.com/ForceBru/PyVM Take a look at how `VM/__init__.py` and `VM/instructions.py` work together.

Comment: @jq170727 That shortens the code, but that doesn't fix the problem. You still need `testfunc.__globals__['nm'] = nm`.

Comment: @ForceBru See, I don't think I can do that with my code. For my code, both files would be dependent upon one another, not just one upon the other.

Comment: @ClaytonGeist, generally, circular dependency (even if it's kinda not because of `if __name__ == "__main__"`) may mean your code needs some redesign. And this may be a source of hard to find bugs as well.

Comment: @ClaytonGeist yes I was just suggesting the more convential import syntax.  I'm sure there are reasons but it's not clear why `nm` can't be a parameter to testfunc.

Comment: @ForceBru Have you programmed GUI functionality with PyQt5? You need to define separate functions for everything if you need more than one command for something like, let's say, a button press. I've got some code already separated, defining the look of the UIs. I've got a whole bunch of functions used for UI functionality. I want to separate many of those functions and put them in their own files. In order to prevent circular dependency, I'd need to use non global variables in the functions, i.e. feeding many variables as parameters into the function that aren't specific to the function.

Comment: @jq170727 Well, imagine it's not just `nm` and `testfunc`. Let's say you have many global variables like `nm` -- 20 of them. Then let's say you have 50 different functions which each use many of those 20 globals. Then, every time, you'd be inputting those 20 variables in as arguments to each of those functions. That's a lot of repetition.

Comment: Maybe have a third module that imports from the other two.